# Iterating Through Columns of a Table and Deleting Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to iterate through a field of values, deleting entire rows if the field value is equal to a variable name. The first iteration is successful, and the row is deleted when the value is detected. However, the next iterations do not work, as the rows that match the value of the variable are not deleted.

```
For y = 0 To Me.inventory_selection.ListCount - 1
    If Me.inventory_selection.Selected(y) Then
        search_loc = Me.inventory_selection.List(y)
        With Worksheets("Records").ListObjects("Inventory")
            For i = .ListRows.count To 1 Step -1
                If .ListColumns("Location").DataBodyRange(i) = search_loc Then
                    .ListRows(i).Delete 'Shift:=xlUp
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End If
Next y
```

I think it may have to do with the row being deleted, and the i value not picking up where it left off. Please let me know what you think, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't think the `i` index is the problem. When you delete a row, the index of all rows below changes, but that does not interfere with your code as your for loop steps -1 (nicely done btw). I don't see any problems in your `i` for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I see you commented the code `Shift:=xlUp`.
But as far as I know if you delete a row, excel will shift the rows up, regardless of mentioning `Shift:=xlUp` or not.
(You can use `clearcontents` instead of `delete` if you do not want to delete the row and shift the others below it.  But I am not sure if this is something you want)